# Value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format - Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I am having a problem when using this library with vue.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment

When I try to pass date in a table, I get this warning:

> Deprecation
> warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.
> moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable
> across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are
> discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please
> refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

This is my code:

```
<small>{{ item.created_at | moment("from", "now", true) }}</small>
```

And this is how my codes without any filtering:

```
2021-10-11 11:17:03
```

I have tried this:

```
   <small>{{ [item.created_at,"YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss a"] | moment("from", "now", true) }}</small>
```

But now get this:

```
app.js Could not build a valid `moment` object from input.
```

Any idea how to fix this warning in vue js please?

Thank you

Comment: Would that not be `moment().fromNow()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your approaches, as you warning tells you, do mismatch RFC2822/ISO8601.

RFC2822 would look like this:

```
01 Jun 2020 14:11:32 -0700
```

ISO8601 would look like this:

```
2021-10-10T22:00:00.000Z
```

If you need to get the date format of `vue-moment` into ISO8601 format, you can do this in a short function like this:

```
showNewDate(date) {
   return new Date(Date.parse(date))
}
```

If you pass `2021-10-11 11:17:03` to this function it will give you `2021-10-11T09:17:03.000Z` which is the date +- your timezone, in my example case minus two hours.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am sorry for the delay in replying to you but I did not receive your answer via email. I only checked my StackOverflow account today and noticed your reply :-)